# Javascript ALT click on link opens alternative link

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to open an alternate link when I click by holding down the alt button. I've tried some solutions but they seem to have weird problems. All I want is when clicking to detect if the alt key is held down

```
function selectlink(selection,alt) {
  if (alt key is pressed) {
  window.open(alt,'_blank');
  } else {
  window.open(selection,'_blank');
}
```

In the body:

```
 <a href="javascript:selectlink('http://www.google.com','http://www.yahoo.com')">Click</a>
```

Preferably WITHOUT Jquery.

Comment: Whether with or without jQuery, you still need to actually do some _event handling_ here.

Comment: I'd put together a test case and see if I could figure this out … but my keyboard doesn't have an alt key.

Comment: Your keyboard doesn't have an alt key? Where'd you dig that up from.

Comment: +CBroe Yes although the code I've come across with event handling caused a lot of problems. Looking for some straightforward solution. The event handling somehow causes it to remember the url sent onclick only once...clicking other links that open the same function always opens the same two links....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) the `event` as a parameter, this will make it possible to check if a key was pressed during the click.

```js
function selectlink(selection, alt, e) {
 if (e.altKey) {
   alert(alt);
  } else {
   alert(selection);
 }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="selectlink('http://www.google.com','http://www.yahoo.com', event)">Click</a>
```

With a little bit of rewriting you can make the link a bit smarter and still have functioning links when javascript is disabled.

```js
function selectLink(e) {
  var el = e.target;

  if (e.altKey) {
    window.open(el.getAttribute("alternative"), '_blank');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="selectLink(event)" alternative="http://www.yahoo.com">Click</a>
```

Comment: exactly, it's a better practice than using return false. Edited my answer to comply :).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using jQuery. I'll write a solution using pure JS in my lunch break.

https://jsfiddle.net/jotq0atz/2/

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" data-alt-href="http://www.facebook.com" id="x">X</a>
```

Here is the js:

```
$("#x").on('click', function(e){
  link = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
  alt_link = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-alt-href');

  if(e.altKey){
    alert("alt was held while clicking");
    window.open(alt_link, '_blank');
  } else {
    alert("alt wasn't held while clicking");
    window.open(link, '_blank');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution made by adapting the answer provided in [javascript alt key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412044/javascript-alt-key)

```
var altdown = false;

document.onkeydown = KeyCheck;

document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       

function KeyCheck(e)
{
   var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
   switch(KeyID)
   {
      case 18:
      document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Alt";
       if(e.type == "keydown"){
         altdown = true;
       }
       else if(e.type == "keyup"){
         altdown = false;
       }
      break; 
   }

}

function selectlink(selection,alt) {
  if (altdown) {
  window.open(alt,'_blank');
  } else {
  window.open(selection,'_blank');
  }
}
```

The link opened in dependent on the altdown variable which is true when the alt key is pressed down. A working fiddle can be seen here. https://jsfiddle.net/q5kr9h2o/7/