# How to register CommandOrControl alone to globalShortcut in electron.js?

Tags: javascript, electron, shortcut

I am working on a tool for dynamically demonstrate what key is press on keyboard. By using ***globalShortcut*** module on electorn.js, I am stuck on how to register ***Control*** or  ***Alt*** key alone:

```
const globalShortcut = require('electron').globalShortcut;

/* Register "ESC" is work */
globalShortcut.register("Escape", () => {
    console.log("Esc")
    win.webContents.send('onInput', "Escape");

  })

/* Register modifiers like "Alt" or "Control" would throw error*/

globalShortcut.register("Alt", () => {
    console.log("Alt")
    win.webContents.send('onInput', "Alt");

  })
```

I am sure every key is resisted successfully except **Available modifiers** which was classified by [official tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/accelerator#available-modifiers). Does anyone know how to fix the problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the alt and or ctrl keys with global shortcuts does not seem like a good idea to me. Because it is global shortcuts it could possibly interfere with other functionality (like ctrl+alt+del). There is a package to help with [electron-local shortcuts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-localshortcut) or you can use the menu to use the shortcuts when the window is focussed as described in the [electron official docs-local shortcuts](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/electron.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/docs/tutorial/keyboard-shortcuts.html).

Additionally, if you are trying to capture these events while the client is in the browser window, it might be preferred to add event listeners to the key up and key down events as so:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', doSomething, true)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412044/javascript-alt-key) are some more examples using the above mentioned method.

Comment: Thanks for your good suggestion. But I want to handle all keyboard event on the global environment. Now I consider to access my goal by using iohook module. If you have any idea please feel free to reply!

Comment: Have you tried mousetrap? I see it is also recommended in their docs, but it should work the same as IOHook conceptually... Sorry I can't be more help

[1][https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap]